# Update databinding for different elements in observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections

till now I have a observable collection with just one type of objects in it, but now I have second type of objects in it. I have bound some wpf elements to elements of this collection, what I now want is that the input forms change depending on which kind of object it binds to in the collection. 
What is the best approach to that?

Comment: Do they extend from a common interface? [Dibs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dibs) on visitor pattern.

Comment: Discard what I said. The correct answer has been posted. +1 to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `DataTemplate` without `x:Key`, but with `DataType={x:Type typename}`. Write one data template for each type in your collection. WPF then automatically selects the data template that matches the type of the item in the collection.

Example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StringType}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BooleanType}">
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
</DataTemplate>
```